# Pass a percent (%) sign in a url and get exact value of it using php

Tags: php, urlencode

I am trying to pass percent (%) sign in url like

```
%B6011000995504101^SB
```

but when I echo, it returns

```
♦011000995504101^SB
```

I want exact same value as I pass it in URL.

I have tried to use urlencode() function, but it give me output like this...

```
%B6011000995504101%5ESB
```

please help me regarding this

Comment: use url_encode() and url_decode() may also require htmlentities() %B6 for example is the code for the blob you got.  passing the % is actually a really bad idea you'd be better off passing a different character for percent or not passing it at all and assume that the % is always there and assign it i nyour script after.

Comment: % is used for urlencode, better to pass a specific pattern like $$ or something else and decode it in the php code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [urlencode but ignore certain chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676209/urlencode-but-ignore-certain-chars)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### Answer:

To send a `%` sign in a url, instead send `%25`.

In your case, in order for php to see a percent sign, you must pass  the character string `%25B6011000995504101^SB` to the server.

### Why:

In URLs, the percent sign has special meaning. Is used to encode special characters. For example, `&` is the separator between parameters, so if you want your parameter to actually *contain* an `&`, you instead write `%26`. Because the percent sign is used to encode special characters, it is *also* a special character, and so if you want to actually send a percent sign, it must also be encoded. The encoding for a percent sign is `%25`.

Comment: it adds another 25 like %2525

Comment: Awesome!! I was beating myself up because of this problem... thx

Comment: If you end up with %2525, that means you're accidentally encoding the string *twice*. Figure out where the encodings are happening, and remove/avoid one of them.

Comment: I had the %2525 issue, the fix for me was to just to use the `urldecode('abc%text')` function.

Answer (score 6):

Before including a raw string in a URL it's a good idea to pass it through urlencode like so:

```
<?php
$original='%B6011000995504101^SB';

$updated=urlencode($original);

echo "<a href=\"some_page.php?$updated\">Link here</a>";
?>
```

The receiving page will know what to do - give this example a try on your webserver:

```
<?php

if($_GET['argument']) {
    echo "<p>You passed in the argument &quot;$_GET[argument]&quot;</p>";
}else {
    echo "<p>No argument was passed.</p>";
}
$original='%B6011000995504101^SB';

$updated=urlencode($original);

echo "<a href=\"urlencode.php?argument=$updated\">Link here</a>";
?>
```

(name the file **urlencode.php**)