# How to send percentage in url?

Tags: php, html, url, search, url-encoding

I am trying to send a url like this for search data

```
http://localhost/project/search/text:75%
```

I am getting `400 - Bad Request` error in here.

I even tried replacing percentage with %25. But it didn't worked. How should I send the search data containing percentage?

Comment: Maybe it's the colon that causes the problem.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: @user4098326 which semicolon are you referring to?

Comment: @user4098326 means "colon", not "semicolon".

Comment: The colon `:` should also be escape as %3A

Comment: As others have mentioned, the colon will also cause problems in the same way as `%` does; it's a reserved character.

Answer (score 1):

In URLs, the `%` percent character is reserved for character encoding.
Usually to represent a `%` character you can use `%25`, but as you have already tried this and that it doesn't work for you, you should instead use [PHP's `urlencode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) like so:

```
$url=urlencode("text:%75");
```

The same issue occurs with `:`, this therefore prevents the same issue with this character also (which for reference is `%3A`).

*Partially from [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342671/pass-a-percent-sign-in-a-url-and-get-exact-value-of-it-using-php)*

Comment: @GaneshBabu.T.Y Your PHP installation has problems then, because the two methods I list work properly.