# How to add percentage in ruby on rails route constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to add percentage and . in search string rails constrains. It's giving No route matches [GET] (Actually it's a GET Request)

Here is my constraint

```
get "/external_id/:external_id",
controller: "XXXXXXX",
action: "show_by_login_name",
constraints: { external_id: /[a-zA-Z0-9.]%+/ }
```

Comment: Please add link examples that you're trying to handle

Comment: @Vasfed


For your reference 



http://localhost:15302/v1/internal/organizations/xxxxxxxxxx/users/external_id/test%ert


http://localhost:15302/v1/internal/organizations/xxxxxxxxxx/users/external_id/test.123

http://localhost:15302/v1/internal/organizations/xxxxxxxxxx/users/external_id/test%ertt.ut

Answer (score 3):

Please modify your regex to use the following code

```
/[0-z\.\%]+/
```

**Explanation:**

Your current regex `/[a-zA-Z0-9.]%+/` reads as:

1. match a single character from the list: `[a-zA-Z0-9.]`
2. match one or more occurrences of `%`

So, if your `:external_id` is: `something%else`, the pattern matches only `g%`.

In the future, if you are not sure about regex, you can always test it with tools such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: The above regex will works  fine but still i am getting bad request 

thanks for your answer.





http://localhost:15302/v1/internal/organizations/xxxxxxxxxx/users/external_id/test%ert



Puma caught this error: bad URI(is not URI?): "/api/organizations/xxxxxxxxxxx/users/external_id/test\u000Et" (URI::InvalidURIError)

Comment: @KrishnaMaheswara when you want to send `%` in the URL, please use `%25` instead (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342786/2039726). Is it working then?