# HTTP Server can not serve files with % character in their names

Tags: python, node.js, linux, http

I created a file by

```
touch s%22.txt
```

Started a HTTP Server by

```
python -m http.server
```

And requested the file by

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/s%22.txt
```

An HTTP Server error was showed:

```
"GET /s%22.txt" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I switched from **http.server** of python to **http-server** of nodejs , and got the same error.

If I replaced the file name with one without a % character, it worked fine.

How can I access a file with a % character in its name by HTTP request?

Comment: try `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/s%2522.txt` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342671/pass-a-percent-sign-in-a-url-and-get-exact-value-of-it-using-php

Comment: Did you try `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/s%2522.txt`  That is, using `%25` to escape `%`

Comment: Oh, it works, thanks!

Comment: % is used for encoding URLs, so that's why you need to escape it like that. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP