# percent(%) sign character in git password

Tags: git, character-encoding

I have git porosity URL as 'https://username:45!!%78&&@git.mx.local/saga-kube.git' but while cloning a remote project, I'm getting errors as

`At line:1 char:52 + git clone ...`

I can pass special characters using that format.

```
!   #   $    &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
%21 %23 %24 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B %3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

How to pass the '%' character in the password?

Pls, note: I cannot change the password.

Comment: Strange %25 seems to be missing from your table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17342786/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For '%' character, equivalent URL encode is '%25'

You can try replacing '%' with '%25'